# F3 Framework Replace String in an array

Tags: sql, fat-free-framework

I'm using the F3 Framwork and need a possibility to replace a value in an array.

```
$car=new Axon('cars');
$list=$car->afind();
```

So I define my array named "list" which has a field "producer_id".
But how can I change the value for the field in this array?
Idea: This array gives me a list of all cars in my cars database. Every car has a producer_id. Prodrucer is a own table in my database with fields like producer_id and producer_name. By a SQL query on this table I want to get the producers_name and insert it into a array.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

Loop through the $list and populate another array with data from another Axon:

```
$names=array();
foreach($list as $i){
    $producers=new Axon('producers');
    $p=$producers->afind('producer_id='.$i['producer_id']);
    $names[]=$p['producer_name'];
}
```

Use SQL and a Join statement:

```
$sql='select cars.*,producers.producers_name from cars left join producers on cars.producer_id=producers.producer_id';
DB:sql($sql);
foreach(F3::get('DB->result') as $row){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Hope that at least gets you started in the right direction.